# jquery function not working for validating when click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when I tried to call the function on the button submit by clicking the function for some reason is not working. So the code should display a text saying that the input should be filled and in the if statement if the input is empty it should display the message

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var submit = $("submit");
  var p_user = $("#user").value;
  submit.on('click', validation());

  function validation() {
    if (p_user == "") {
      $("#user").after("you must fill this item");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<form class="form" action="index.html" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="usuario" id="user">
  <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="nombre">
  <input type="password" name="contraseña" placeholder="contraseña" id="contraseña">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things

- You are getting the value for the `p_user` like below

  ```
  var p_user = $("#user").value;
  ```
- You should first of all change the `value` to `.val()` , as jquery does not have `value` property javascript do.
- Then move this inside the `validation()` function because it would always have the empty value even if you type in.

Try using the `submit` event for the form, so rather than binding the `click` event on the button bind `submit` event of the form and use `e.preventDefault()` to stop the form submission and use your custom validation function to display error messages, see a demo below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var form = $(".form");
  form.on('submit', function(e) {

    if (validation() === false) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });

  function validation(e) {
    var p_user = $("#user").val();
    $('.error-label').remove();
    if (p_user == "") {
      $("#user").after("<span class='error-label'>you must fill this item</span>");
      return false;
    } else {
      //submit the form
      return true;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.error-label {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<form class="form" action="index.html" method="post">

  <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="usuario" id="user">

  <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="nombre">

  <input type="password" name="contraseña" placeholder="contraseña" id="contraseña">

  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
submit.on('click' , validation());
```

to

```
submit.on('click' , validation);
```

By including the parenthesis, you are actually causing function to be fired right then instead of telling it to fire on click.

https://jsfiddle.net/djmatwhc/1/